# Trying to set focus programmatically does not work with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a problem **in Firefox** trying to set the focus to a control using <s>jquery</s>javascript. While my specific problem is quite involved, even the simple test case below does not work for me. The input is found, its value is changed but the input is not focused.
Issue present with Firefox only

Tried with Firefox 44.0.2 on Windows 7
It works as it should with MS IE 10 and Chrome

```js
$().ready(function() {
  $("#I").val(3);
  $("#I").focus(); // JQuery focus - does not work
  
  var ctl = document.getElementById('I')
  ctl.value='DOM';
  ctl.focus(); // DOM Native focus - does not work
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=I>
```

Comment: Works for me in your snippet in the question!

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm trying the snippet in different browser right now. Fail in firefox. Did you tried with ... ?

Comment: I know. Try giving `$(document).ready(` instead?

Comment: The function *is* called, the value *is* set. It's just the focus thing

Comment: Great... See the below answer.

Comment: Works on FF45 on mac

Answer (score 2):

This style of ready event:

```
$().ready(function() {
```

Long ago deprecated and better not to use it.

---

You can use `autofocus` attribute:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#I').val(3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=I autofocus>
```

and instead of jQuery's try triggerring the DOM `.focus()` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#I').val(3);
  $('#I')[0].focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=I>
```

Comment: The `autofocus` attribute is underused and almost unknown. Good advice.

Comment: As I wrote: `my specific problem is quite involved` I need to focus in a specific moment, autofocus is of no use

Comment: @edc65 in that case you could instead try the `.focus()` DOM event.

Comment: Do you mean DOM focus method? I'll try

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried DOM focus method. Same problem. It's really a Firefox issue

Comment: About the snippet: it's a simplified example! The style of ready event is not what we are talking about - please (then: no. it's not deprecated at all. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is an issue with setting focus on Firefox, there is a workaround which involves using [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/). See below:

```js
$().ready(function() {

    $('#I').val(3);

    $('#I').focusout(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).focus();
        }, 0);
    });

    $('#I').focus();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="I" />
```

Comment: It sets the focus at start of the input on FF45 Mac, it may need some setSelectionRange()

Comment: @Kaiido sure if you want to select what is in the the input, but OP may want to set focus to input because there is noting in it.

Comment: Or he may want to prefix the input and let the user fill what comes after, as in OPost. Then it's more convenient to set the caret at the end of the input, and that is where setSelectionRange is usefull, not only to select some text ;-)